Updation of an object as a value of a field not happening in mongo db
const  Users = require('../mongodb/models/users')

const normalize = async function(email,genre){
    const user = await Users.find({email:email})
    console.log(email)
    console.log(user)
    const minLikes = user[0].normalizationlikes[0].min
    const maxLikes = user[0].normalizationlikes[0].max
    const updatedLikes = { ...user[0].likes[0].raw };  // Spread the existing likes into a new object
    console.log(minLikes)
    console.log(maxLikes)
    console.log(updatedLikes)
    console.log(genre)
    console.log(updatedLikes[genre])
    console.log(updatedLikes.educational)
    console.log(isNaN(updatedLikes[genre])); // Check if it's NaN
    updatedLikes[genre] += 1;  // Increment the like count for the specified category
    console.log(updatedLikes)
    const normalizedLikes = {};
    for (let category in updatedLikes) {
        normalizedLikes[category] = (updatedLikes[category] - minLikes) / (maxLikes - minLikes);
    }
    console.log(updatedLikes)
    console.log(normalizedLikes)
   await Users.updateOne(
        {email:email},
        {$set:{"likes.0.raw": updatedLikes }}
    )
     await Users.updateOne(
        {email:email},
        {$set:{"likes.0.normalized":normalizedLikes}}
    )
    return normalizedLikes;
}
module.exports = normalize

In this everything is going perfect normalization and all going perfectly. But the updation in the database is not happening. Even the output shows everything correctly
{
  adventure: 0,
  action: 1,
  comedy: 0,
  drama: 0,
  fantasy: 0,
  horror: 0,
  romance: 0,
  sciencefiction: 0,
  thriller: 0,
  mystery: 0,
  documentary: 0,
  musical: 0,
  western: 0,
  anime: 0,
  educational: 0
}
{
  adventure: 0,
  action: 0.01,
  comedy: 0,
  drama: 0,
  fantasy: 0,
  horror: 0,
  romance: 0,
  sciencefiction: 0,
  thriller: 0,
  mystery: 0,
  documentary: 0,
  musical: 0,
  western: 0,
  anime: 0,
  educational: 0
}

But in the mongo db atlas it is not updating. Everything console logs perfectly. Just in the updation part it is not working

could you please share your users model code ?

https://pastecord.com/guvojegeqi.properties
